# Does $a \equiv b \equiv 5 \pmod {12}$ imply $A \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, under the given conditions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Let $a$ be prime, and let $b$ be a positive integer.

Suppose that I know that $a \equiv b \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ holds in general.

Additionally, assume that I know that the following biconditionals hold:
$$(A \equiv 1 \pmod 4) \iff (a \equiv b \pmod 8)$$
$$(A \equiv 3 \pmod 4) \iff (a \equiv b + 4 \pmod 8)$$

If I know that $a \equiv b \equiv 5 \pmod {12}$, then what can I conclude about $A$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $a \equiv b \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ holds in general, then $4 \mid (a - b)$.

Suppose to the contrary that $A \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  This means that $a \equiv b \pmod 8$, which is equivalent to $8 \mid (a - b)$.

But we know that $a \equiv b \equiv 5 \pmod {12}$.  In particular, $4 \mid 12 \mid (a - b)$.  This contradicts (?) $8 \mid (a - b)$.  Hence, we conclude that
$$a \equiv b \equiv 5 \pmod {12} \implies A \equiv 3 \pmod 4.$$

**QUESTION**

> Is this argument logically sound?  If not, how can it be mended so as to produce a valid proof?

Comment: There is no reason to think that because $4$ and $12$ divide $a-b$, that means that it cannot be the case that $8$ divides $a-b$. You have no warrant to claim this is contradicted. For a specific example, take $a=b=5$.

Comment: $4\mid12\mid(a-b)$ does not necessarily contradict $8\mid(a-b)$

Comment: you can't conclude anything. The condition mod 3 makes no contribution to the condition mod 8.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, everyone!  Can somebody please write up an answer, so that I could upvote then accept (and so that this question does not remain in the unanswered queue)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this argument is not logically good as we cannot say that the condition $\mod 3$ contradicts the condition $\mod 8$; or to write in maths: $4 \mid 12 \mid (a-b)$ does not contradict $8 \mid (a-b)$.

Answer (score 0):

No. What you fail to realize is $A$ may not be $a$ . Also, that  being divisible by 2 multiples of the same number, is possible be being a multiple of their LCM . That means we can turn one of the biconditionals to:

$$(A \equiv 1 \pmod 4) \iff (a \equiv b \pmod {24})$$